# Mismatched hreflang and HTML lang declarations and cannonicals

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, canonical-link, polylang, hreflang

there is a redirect I tried to do on my site, but I am quite confused in it.  First of all, I have SSL installed on the site and I use non-www domain redirect. In the .htaccess file below 301 redirect to https://. If I need to summarize the situation, domainame.com is directing to the default https://domainname.com/tr/ and https://domainname.com/en/ I have 2 languages ​​in my rop and there are confusion in the cannonical part, thank you if you can help. I'm using WP and polylang

.htaccess file

```
#Jet pack broken Stats
AllowOverride FileInfo Limit

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
```

this code is in functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'pll_rel_hreflang_attributes', 'filter_pll_rel_hreflang_attributes', 10, 1 ); 

// Define the pll_rel_hreflang_attributes callback.
function filter_pll_rel_hreflang_attributes( $hreflangs ) {

    foreach ( $hreflangs as $lang => $url ) {
        if ( $lang === 'en' ) {
            printf( '<link rel="cannonical" href=”http://domainname.com/en/” />');
            printf( '<link rel="alternate" href="%s" hreflang="%s" /><!-- country code en-US-->' . "\n", esc_url( $url ), esc_attr( 'en-US' ) );
        }
        elseif ( $lang === 'tr' ) {
            printf( '<link rel="cannonical" href=”http://domainname.com/tr/” />');
            printf( '<link rel="alternate" href="%s" hreflang="%s" /><!-- country code tr-TR-->' . "\n", esc_url( $url ), esc_attr( 'tr-TR' ) );
        }
    }
    return $hreflangs; 
};
```